# Troubles with keyboardEvent.shiftKey in Chrome

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-chrome, haxe

I'd met a very strange problem. Take a look at the following code:

```
Lib.current.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPressed);
...
private static function onKeyPressed(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    trace(e.shiftKey);
}
```

if you press any key (except SHIFT) `false` is outputed. Press SHIFT+ALT (first press SHIFT and then ALT). Then after pressing of any key `true` is outputed. Note that if I press SHIFT, press of any key will output `false` again.

you may download swf containing code listed above from [here](http://upload.comapping.com/13166079772251).

**IMPORTANT:** I have this issue only on Chrome, e.g. on Firefox everything is ok.

**Note:** If that's important, I'm working with Haxe languge, not with AS3.

Any thoughts will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into `chrome://plugins/` in a new tab. Check and see if under the flash section you have more than 1 flash plugins installed for Chrome. If so, disable the older version(s) and then try your test again.

Comment: after I disabled FP 10.3 all works fine. Looks like it's really FP bug

Answer (score 1):

That's a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94240). It should work fine in tomorrow's canary build (16.0.890.0) and will be fixed on stable in a week or two.

**Absolutely do not disable the built-in Flash. It will leave you with an outdated and unsandboxed version of Flash.**